# Android failed to use HTTP method POST

Tags: android, http, http-post

So, I have this code in my Activity (layout is supporting user interface for button which triggers method `onSaveRegistrationClick`):

```
public void onSaveRegistrationClick (View view){

    postData();

}

public void postData(){

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.mywebsite.com");

    try 
    {
        httpclient.execute(httppost);
    } catch (Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Not working" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

On my website, I have index.php which on call saves one row in database which helps me determine if Android connected to site. However, I'm getting exceptions on line `httpclient.execute(httppost);`. Where am I mistaking?

P.S. - I have permission added in AndroidManifest.xml (I added even extra, i.e.:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>    
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DOWNLOAD_WITHOUT_NOTIFICATION" />
```

Comment: What does the logcat say?

Comment: Nothing, because exception is caught. But, when I move catch, it writes:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: could not execute the method of an activity

Comment: Make sure you are doing networking task on non-ui thread! Starting version 3.0 Android has became more religious and it wont let you perform networking task on main thread.

Comment: @VipulShah: thanks, it helped, although I need to struggle now how to pass parameters in thread.

Answer (score 0):

The error is that you must to use a thread and not a function,
try this:

```
new MyTask().execute();
```

that call it to the process

```
private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    String textResult;
    private Exception exception;


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids)
    { ...your code }
```